# How to turn off JTextPane line wrapping?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Unlike `JTextArea`, `JTextPane` has no option to turn line wrapping off. I found one [solution](http://java-sl.com/wrap.html) to turning off line wrapping in `JTextPane`s, but it seems too verbose for such a simple problem. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [No Wrap Text Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/).  Here's the code included from the link.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
noWrapPanel.add( textPane );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( noWrapPanel );
```

Comment: The only thing wrapping the `JTextPane` in a `JPanel` did was disable the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @Jeffrey, works fine for me using JDK6_7 (and earlier versions) on XP. I don't think I'd go to all the trouble of creating a blog entry if it didn't work. Post your SSCCE that shows how you tested it.

Comment: @Jeffrey, NEVER set the preferred size of a component you add to a scrollpane. If you do then the scrollpane can't do its job. Instead set the preferred size of the scrollpane.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Updated the SSCCE and image. Now I have vertical scrolling, but it's still line wrapping.

Comment: @Jeffrey, you need to add the panel to the scrollpane.

Comment: The panel is passed to `JScrollPane.setViewportView(Component)` when you call the constructor. Using `JScrollPane.add(Component)` doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I know how a scrollpane works (I always set the viewport via the constructor). If you don't understand what I'm suggesting then please copy the 4 lines of code from the blog that demonstrates how to do this. That is what you should have done from the start!

Comment: What's the difference between my code and the code on the blog post?

Comment: Last comment. This is taking too much time. All you have to do is copy the code and test it! Thats why I included the code. You are creating the JScrollPane with the "textpane". The blog creates the JScrollPane with the "noWrapPanel".

Comment: Oopsies. I tested the posted code, but changed it to `new JScrollPane(panel)` in my IDE so I didn't see anything wrong with the code. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 4):

The [No Wrap Text Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) also provides an alternative solution that doesn't require wrapping the `JTextPane` in a `JPanel`, instead it overrides `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()`.  I prefer that solution, but it didn't quite work for me - I noticed that wrapping still occurs if the viewport becomes narrower than the minimum width of the `JTextPane`.

I found that `JEditorPane` is overriding `getPreferredSize()` to try and 'fix' things when the viewport is too narrow by returning the minimum width instead of the preferred width.  This can be resolved by overriding `getPreferredSize()` again to say 'no, really - we always want the actual preferred size':

```
public class NoWrapJTextPane extends JTextPane {
    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        // Only track viewport width when the viewport is wider than the preferred width
        return getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width 
            <= getParent().getSize().width;
    };

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // Avoid substituting the minimum width for the preferred width when the viewport is too narrow
        return getUI().getPreferredSize(this);
    };
}
```