# Disable automatic scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have added a JScrollPane to a JTextPane , i have try to set the vertical bar to zero , thus it will appear as it was not scroll. In fact my aim  is to disable the automatic scroll to the right and down . Below is my code

`JTextPane jtp1 = new JTextPane();                                                                                                  jtp1.setText("bhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhbhbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbhbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b");
jtp1.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane scrollpane2 = new JScrollPane(jtp1,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollpane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You want scroll bar to be displayed only if needed means content is not visible in current height.

Comment: no , disable automatic  scrolling

Comment: You want to disable vertical scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to turn off wrapping in a text pane. The solution is to add the text pane to a JPanel using a BorderLayout and then add the panel to the scroll pane:

Try below code

```
JTextPane jtp1 = new JTextPane();
jtp1.setText("bhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhbhbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbhbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b");
jtp1.setEditable(false);

JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
noWrapPanel.add( jtp1 );

JScrollPane scrollpane2 = new JScrollPane(noWrapPanel);

JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.add(scrollpane2);
frame.setSize(200,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Also look at [JTextPane line wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156038/jtextpane-line-wrapping)