# How to avoid new line / line wrap inside JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextpane

How can I deactivate/avoid lines being wrapped around inside a JTextPane?

This is what usually will happen once I enter text into the pane and the horizontal space is not enough:

[image]

I would like to avoid the second line and continue writing in one single line (even without a scroll bar) where I can navigate using the arrow keys (left/right).

Comment: Maybe this gives you a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156038/jtextpane-line-wrapping

Comment: Thx I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thx for the link - it's working!